# Is there a way to automate file upload for a Postman Put request?

Tags: automated-tests, postman

I'm looking at automating the API tests for the project I'm working on, but there are some APIs that require an image file to be part of the PUT request for a picture upload.  Is there a way to have postman automatically use a predetermined file so that the entire API suite can be run automatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use newman since postman doesn't support uploading of file in runner mode